# NPE while running unit test in scalatest

Tags: unit-testing, nullpointerexception, sbt, scalatest

I'm getting this `NullPointerException` that I don't understand.

```
subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite) with arguments: 

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework$RunConfig$.decreaseLatch(ScalaTestFramework.scala:176)
at org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework$ScalaTestRunner.run(ScalaTestFramework.scala:336)
at org.scalatools.testing.Runner2.run(Runner2.java:16)
at sbt.TestRunner.delegateRun(TestFramework.scala:57)
at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:51)
at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:71)
at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:80)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TestFramework.scala:178)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TestFramework.scala:178)
at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:190)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$7.apply(TestFramework.scala:178)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$7.apply(TestFramework.scala:178)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeParallel$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Tests.scala:119)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeParallel$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Tests.scala:119)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:47)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:47)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)




java.lang.RuntimeException: Tests unsuccessful
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:123)
at sbt.Tests$.showResults(Tests.scala:192)
at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$6.apply(Defaults.scala:296)
at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$6.apply(Defaults.scala:294)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf4$1.apply(Structure.scala:580)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf4$1.apply(Structure.scala:580)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Has anyone seen this? Any solutions?

Comment: which version of scalatest are you using?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do that leads this exception?